# AWS Elasticbeanstalk and Tomcat Server running jaxrs webservice

Tags: hibernate, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jax-rs

I have deployed a web application made on top of JAX-RS.I have deployed this webservice on aws elasticbeanstalk. Problem is that in each 24 to 48hrs my web app is used to crash and it does not respond.When I restart the app from the aws console window it again runs smoothly for next 24 to 48hrs and again crashes.Please help I am not understanding why it is happening.

Comment: which type of server you are using? any error logs?

Comment: I am using tomcat server 8.0 running on aws elasticbeanstalk. I am not getting the actual error.It just stops working within 48 hours.

Comment: i mean which ec2 instance type, you using ? is it micro,small , mid , large ?

Comment: its micro instance

Comment: I am not understanding difference in micro, large, small. will u please guide regarding that?

Comment: can u change the instance type to at least medium, we were also having similar problem, but in instance logs we saw some cpu spikes , so we changed to medium and after that our problem resoved.

Comment: well what is the difference among them?

Comment: Where can I see the log details?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: just check and let me know if it works?

Comment: okk.............